Migrations not getting applied , deleted the migrations folder in django
I deleted the migrations folder in one of my app folders of the project now when I run makemigrations I am getting No changes detected ..please help
I was expecting that migrations folder will be created with the migration files

Is the app added to INSTALLED_APPS?
